# wrapper.setValue() cannot be called on EL-INPUT

Tags: node.js, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm trying call a Vue component for unit test with Jest, I want do it set value a input text field. this is my "file.vue"

```html
<el-form-item label="Nombre" data-test="id-form">
              <el-input
                v-model="data.nombre"
                maxlength="45"
                @blur="v$.data.nombre.$touch()"
                data-test="nombre_caja"
              ></el-input>
              <div v-if="v$.data.nombre.$error" class="text-danger                  text-xs">
                <small
                  v-for="error in v$.data.nombre.$errors"
                  :key="error.index"
                  >{{ error.$message }}</small
                >
              </div>
 </el-form-item>
```

My test code is

```html
 it('Set value',async()=> {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(ModalNuevaCaja)

    const input = wrapper.find('[data-test="nombre_caja"]')

    await input.setValue({nombre:'New value'})

    expect(input.element.value).toBe('New Value')
```

And the error message is:

```html
wrapper.setValue() cannot be called on EL-INPUT

      26 |     const input = wrapper.find('[data-test="nombre_caja"]')
      27 |
    > 28 |    await input.setValue({nombre:'New value'})
         |                ^
      29 |
      30 |    expect(input.element.value).toBe('New value')
      31 |
```

I'm new doing this and would appreciate any advice. Thank!!

Answer (score 3):

`wrapper.find()` returns a `DOMWrapper`. The `setValue()` implementation on the `DOMWrapper` only allows you to use it on `input`, `textarea`, 'select`, etc.

You should use `findComponent()` in order to retrieve a `VUEWrapper`, on which you can call `setValue()`.

```js
 it('Set value', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(ModalNuevaCaja)

    const input = wrapper.findComponent('[data-test="nombre_caja"]')

    await input.setValue('New value')

    expect(input.element.value).toBe('New Value')
})
```